# How to print text messages into console

Tags: linux, opengl

When I compile and run example programs from OpenGL SuperBible under Linux no console window is created and as a result I can't see any text messages. Here by text messages I mean the output of `printf` function. This does happen under Windows - running exe opens a console window alongside the rendering window and all text messages appear in that console window.

How to I get console message printed into terminal window under Linux?

Comment: So start the program from a terminal, and its stdout/stderr will be attached to that terminal.  What's your question, btw?

Answer (score 2):

Run it in a terminal window, you'll then see the output.

If you don't see any output, check out the command line options (you'll probably have to pass `-h or --help`or something as argument).

Comment: No output even when run from terminal window.

Comment: @pic11 See my edit, that will probably help.